# PL/SQL - Why ORA-06550 can't be trapped in an exception?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

I created a plsql program to get an employee_id from substitution variable. whenever i try to input a letter, i get an error message with ORA-06550 as the error number. I put it in the exception section but it seems like it wasn't being raised.

here's the error message when i input 'kk' in the substitution variable...

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 13, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'KK' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

and here's my pl/sql block

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off
declare
  cursor cur(mid employees.employee_id%type) is
  select e.last_name employee, 
         m.last_name manager 
    from employees e 
    join employees m 
      on m.employee_id = e.manager_id
   where m.employee_id=mid;

   rec cur%rowtype;
   m_id employees.employee_id%type;
   ex exception;
   pragma exception_init(ex, -06550);

begin
  m_id := &id;
  open cur(m_id);
  fetch cur into rec;
    dbms_output.put_line('here '||rec.employee || ' ' || rec.manager);
  close cur;

exception
  when ex then dbms_output.put_line('employee_id was not a valid number');
end;
/
```

do anyone knows why i cant trap that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could comment. Can't you change your code to:

```
m_id := '&id';
```

so you won't need to trap that exception.

Update for catching number exception:

```
declare
    (...)
begin
    m_id := to_number('&id');
    (...)
exception
    when VALUE_ERROR then
         dbms_output.put_line('You provided invalid number'); 
end;
```

Comment: yes i could do that but i need a number input from the user, and if the user type a letter, that's the only time an exception will trap them from which i got some problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot catch that exception at runtime, because this is a compile-time error.

> m_id := &id;

Try typing `'KK'` instead of `KK`, otherwise it will be interpreted as an identifier.

Comment: yes it is from the substitution variable. It works, thanks. Does it mean i can't trap an error if it doesn't have the ' ' ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely correct. kindly use the employee ID instead of KK, which is in the table. It must be a number. For example 101 or 102

In where clause of the cursor you have use "m.employee_id=mid" and the datatype of employee_id  is number.

Thanks:)